# Calling a function using AJAX not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, csv, file-upload

I have an `AJAX` call that calls a function in a `PHP` file and returns some `JSON`. It looks like this.

```
$('#uploadCustomerForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/resources/submit.php?action=uploadCustomers",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data.success);
        },
        error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert('Uh oh, we could not upload your customers.');
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

This `AJAX` eventually calls this `PHP` function:

```
function uploadCustomers($file_name) {
            // Now we just have to open and read
            $myfile = fopen($file_name, "r") or die("Unable to open file.");
            $columns = fgetcsv($myfile);
            //$sortedColumns = sortColumns($columns); // works when this line is commented out
            while(!feof($myfile)) {
                $row = fgetcsv($myfile);
            }
            fclose($myfile);
            return json_encode(array('success' => $row));
        }
```

This is my first time using `AJAX` to upload a file. I know that execution is getting to the `PHP` function with the correct parameters, because I am able to open the file, and view the `$row`s when the function works. (When the `sortColumns` function is commented.)

When I call `sortColumns`, to get the CSV fields in the order we are looking for, the function suddenly does not work anymore. Right now, this is my `sortColumns` function.

```
function sortColumns($columns) {
            return $columns;
        }
```

Where am I going wrong? I suspect it is either something glaringly obvious, or some `AJAX` rule that I am not following. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your while loop makes no sense. it's a WHILE loop, implying you've got multiple lines of CSV data, but you're doing `$row = ...`, which causes you to save only the **LAST** line retrieved from the file.

Comment: I hope you've got it set up as [`<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)?

Comment: @MarcB yes I know, I am just trying to get it to work, the JSON eventually is printed to the console, so one line of data is enough right now.

Comment: @Blazemonger yes I do.

Comment: mmm i think the problem is one line of data. if fgetscsv is hitting end of file, you are not going inside the loop. And you have anything to encode. so you get nothing. Do you have more than one row in the file? What response do you get? 500 or 200 from the ajax call?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi yes, the file has 500 `.csv` records, all on separate lines.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi 200 when the sortColumns function is commented out, 500 otherwise.

Comment: In what way does the function not work?

Comment: So cmon the answer is in the php log file, it will save you headaches. in a standard linux distro should be on /var/log/httpd/error_log or ssl_error_log. Please check there you won't waste any time anymore. If you are getting 500 the alert('uh oh....') is getting out, Ajax is completely fine, just some php error.

Comment: @dan08 the server returns 500 when the function is called, and 200 when it is not called.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi thank you for your help, the log file said I was calling an undefined function `sortColumns`, turns out, I needed the $this keyword before calling the function.

Comment: `$this` is a reserved keyword in PHP in objects. Where is your object, what the name of it, where do you instantiate that, and where do you want it call that method?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AndreaBogazzi for pointing me to the location of the log file.

The log file said I was calling an undefined function, it turns out, I needed to call the function by:

```
$this->sortColumns($columns);
```

Comment: What is that `$this`. Did you instantiate an object?

Comment: The function is part of a class, but I didn't realize the `$this` keyword was mandatory when calling another function in the same class.

Comment: When you where planning to tell us that you were inside a class? eheheh :)

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi I didn't realize that was such an important detail, I do now!